# Verify overloaded method execution in Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to make Mockito validate a call to library function which code cannot be changed else would have changed signature of varargs to publish(Record record, Record... records)

```
publish(Record record)
publish(Record... records)
```

To validate execution of second function, using following code

```
verify(publisher).publish(ArgumentMatchers.<Record>any());
```

However above call always keep try to check for publish call with NonArgs function and fails. Any suggestions how to make Mockito to check for var args function.

> Used mockito Version for this test is 3.11.2

Comment: Does `any(Record[].class)` work?

Comment: any(Record[].class) fails with

publisher.publish(
    <any org.abc.Record[]>
);
Actual invocations have different arguments:
publisher.publish(
    {"a":"aa"},
    {"b":"bb"},
    {"c":"cc"}
);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick a right overload when you call the verify method.

```java
Mockito.verify(publisher).publish(ArgumentMatchers.<MyRecord[]>any());
```

By specifying `ArgumentMatchers.<MyRecord>any()` you picked the wrong overload .

Notes:

- `any()` implements `VarargMatcher` - a special marker interface meaning that this matcher can be used mo match varargs
- each vararg is matched by `VarargMatcher` separately, in a for loop

Other notes:

- Record is a keyword in modern Java, you might consider renaming your class to sth different